# SQL Server : delete previous rows based on the value in current row

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with these columns: Author_name, country, status.

```
    Author_name       country       status
-------------------------------------------
1   Author - 1  Country - 1 name    remove
2   Author - 2  Country - 2 name    done
3   Author - 3  Country - 3 name    done
4   Author - 4  Country - 4 name    done
5   Author - 5  Country - 5 name    done
6   Author - 6  Country - 6 name    remove
7   Author - 7  Country - 7 name    remove
8   Author - 8  Country - 8 name    done
9   Author - 9  Country - 9 name    remove
10  Author - 10 Country - 10 name   done
```

Expected functionality: when a 'remove' is encountered, that row has to be deleted and the row above it has to be deleted.

If 'remove' appears consecutively, that many rows on top has to be deleted.
location of 'remove' and number of records are not constant.

Once the SQL script has been run, the output of the above table should be:

```
     Author_name      country        status
-------------------------------------------
2    Author - 2  Country - 2 name    done
3    Author - 3  Country - 3 name    done
10   Author - 10 Country - 10 name   done
```

Hope you understood the logic.

I tried using lag, cursor and some other as well. Now I am trying with while loop. Please help me with this. Here is my latest code.

My DB is SQL Server, and currently I am using a online compiler: https://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler

```
CREATE Table tblAuthors
(
   Author_name nvarchar(50),
   country nvarchar(50),
   prod varchar(50),
   timestamp datetime 
)

Declare @Id int
Set @Id = 1

While @Id <= 10
Begin 
   Insert Into tblAuthors values ('Author - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)),
              'Country - ' + CAST(@Id as nvarchar(10)) + ' name', 'done', getdate())
   Print @Id
   Set @Id = @Id + 1
End

update tblAuthors set prod = 'remove' where  Author_name  = 'Author - 1'
update tblAuthors set prod = 'remove' where  Author_name  = 'Author - 6'
update tblAuthors set prod = 'remove' where  Author_name  = 'Author - 7'
update tblAuthors set prod = 'remove' where  Author_name  = 'Author - 9'

SELECT * FROM tblAuthors

select IDENTITY(int, 1,1) as idnt,*  into ##temp_tblAuthors from tblAuthors

select * from ##temp_tblAuthors


DECLARE @intFlag INT = 1
DECLARE @Flag INT = 0
DECLARE  @Author_name nvarchar(50)
DECLARE @country nvarchar(50)
DECLARE  @prod varchar(50)
DECLARE @idnt INT

select @Flag = count(*) from ##temp_tblAuthors

WHILE (@intFlag <=@Flag)
BEGIN

select 
 @idnt = idnt
,@Author_name = Author_name
,@country = country
,@prod = prod 
from ##temp_tblAuthors where idnt = @intFlag

if @prod = 'remove' 
BEGIN 

SELECT  @intFlag
select 
 @idnt = idnt
,@Author_name = Author_name
,@country = country
,@prod = prod 
from ##temp_tblAuthors where idnt = @intFlag-1

DELETE tblAuthors WHERE 
Author_name = @Author_name AND 
country = @country  AND 
prod  = @prod

select 
 @idnt = idnt
,@Author_name = Author_name
,@country = country
,@prod = prod 
from ##temp_tblAuthors where idnt = @intFlag

DELETE tblAuthors WHERE 
Author_name = @Author_name AND 
country = @country  AND 
prod  = @prod



END 

SET @intFlag = @intFlag + 1
END
GO

SELECT * FROM tblAuthors
```

Comment: Datasets in SQL are explicitly ***unordered***.  There is no "row above".  You need a column *(or columns)* you can use in an `ORDER BY` to assert an order.  Do you have such a column?  *(Such as a timestamp for when the row was inserted?)*

Comment: Hi @MatBailie yes, there is an identity column ,hope we can use the same.

Comment: An identity column is not ***guaranteed*** to be in order, it ***is*** possible for a row to have an identity value lower the a pre-existing row.  *(Best practice is to never infer anything from an identity column, and only use it as a unique identifier)*  Do you have other columns?

Comment: @MatBailie ..thanks for the reply ..I am currently developing the DB, I can add a timestamp column. hope that solves the order by issue.

Comment: @MatBailie timestamp column is added...I am still trying to figure out the deletion process.

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience caused...@marc_s
I am trying multiple codes, I didn't pay much attention to keywords. I will make sure, this wont repeat in next posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you ***work backwards***, you can total up a "score" where `'remove'` has `-1` and `'done'` has `+1`.

```
    Author_name   Country             Status    Score
------------------------------------------------------
1   Author - 1    Country - 1 name    remove     2
2   Author - 2    Country - 2 name    done       3
3   Author - 3    Country - 3 name    done       2
4   Author - 4    Country - 4 name    done       1
5   Author - 5    Country - 5 name    done       0
6   Author - 6    Country - 6 name    remove    -1
7   Author - 7    Country - 7 name    remove     0
8   Author - 8    Country - 8 name    done       1
9   Author - 9    Country - 9 name    remove     0
10  Author - 10   Country - 10 name   done       1   <- Start from here
```

Example SQL:

```
SELECT
  *,
  SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'remove' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
    OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC)
      AS score
FROM
  tblAuthors
```

Then, you only want to keep the rows where (still working backwards) the score is higher than the score has ever been so far.

```
    Author_name   Country             Status    Score   PreviousMax
--------------------------------------------------------------------
1   Author - 1    Country - 1 name    remove     2      3
2   Author - 2    Country - 2 name    done       3      2    <- KEEP
3   Author - 3    Country - 3 name    done       2      1    <- KEEP 
4   Author - 4    Country - 4 name    done       1      1
5   Author - 5    Country - 5 name    done       0      1
6   Author - 6    Country - 6 name    remove    -1      1
7   Author - 7    Country - 7 name    remove     0      1
8   Author - 8    Country - 8 name    done       1      1
9   Author - 9    Country - 9 name    remove     0      1
10  Author - 10   Country - 10 name   done       1      NULL <- KEEP
```

You can do this with...

```
WITH
  scored_rows AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'remove' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC)
        AS score
  FROM
    tblAuthors
),
  checked_scored_rows AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(score)
      OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           )
             AS previous_max_score
  FROM
    scored_rows
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  checked_scored_rows
WHERE
  score > COALESCE(previous_max_score, 0)
;
```

This leads you too...

```
WITH
  scored_rows AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status = 'remove' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC)
        AS score
  FROM
    tblAuthors
),
  checked_scored_rows AS
(
  SELECT
    *,
    MAX(score)
      OVER (ORDER BY timestamp DESC, id DESC
                ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
           )
             AS previous_max_score
  FROM
    scored_rows
)
DELETE
  tblAuthors
FROM
  checked_scored_rows
WHERE
      checked_scored_rows.id     = tblAuthors.id
  AND checked_scored_rows.score <= COALESCE(checked_scored_rows.previous_max_score, 0)
```

I believe this demonstrates what you want: https://rextester.com/ZNNB32798